# Using Intent in an Android application

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android application, I have two activity classes. I have a button on the first one and I want to show the second when it is clicked, but I get an error. Here are the classes:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bun) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(bun);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.skipp);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity (new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MCActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        finish();
    }


}
```

Second class:

```
public class MCActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And i have added

```
<activity android:name=".MCActivity" />
```

in manifest too,within `<application>` tags...

Still have the run time error **activity stopped unexpectedly** when i click on button b..

Comment: What does the LogCat say?

Comment: Are you sure you have included button with id skipp in splash.xml ?

Comment: Please paste your LogCat HERE.

Comment: What is in LogCat? Some times you need to clear your project

Comment: LogCat

06-11 17:58:44.997: D/dalvikvm(548): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 757 objects / 55120 bytes in 268ms
06-11 17:58:51.167: D/AndroidRuntime(548): Shutting down VM
06-11 17:58:51.167: W/dalvikvm(548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {cloud.mobile/cloud.mobile.SplashActivity} did not call through to super.onPause()

Comment: 06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3338)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)

Comment: 06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: 06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-11 17:58:51.206: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

Comment: Splash.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/amel"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skipp"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/skip"
        android:text="Button" android:layout_marginLeft="75dp" android:layout_marginTop="350dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: @Vipul Shah

Yes the id is skipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write Below onPause() Code

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

instead of your onPause Code.

Comment: if i try your onPause Code this is giving me error but if i change onPause code and than it's working.